# AspectJ and Wicket throws nullpointer for Injector

Tags: hibernate, wicket, aspectj

I have wicket aspectj application which uses hibernate annotated classes and uses a DAO service layer.

I have developed an updatetask that does not run in an applicationcontext. Therefor i created a main method and loaded the context as a global variable.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(LOCATIONS);
    XS2RAWebApp webApp = new XS2RAWebApp() {
        @Override
        public void init() {
            getComponentInstantiationListeners().add(new SpringComponentInjector(this, context,true));
        }
    };
    ThreadContext.setApplication(webApp);
    ResponseUpdateTask updatetask = new ResponseUpdateTask();

    updatetask.run();
}
```

As you can see, the SpringComponentInjector provided with a springcomponent injector.

In this update task i want to save some data with hibernate.

I have Hibernate entity and inside this entity i have a reference to my service DAO.

```
@MappedSuperclass()
public abstract class Entiteit {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Entiteit.class);

    @SpringBean()
    @Transient
    private transient DataAccessHelper daoHelper;
    ...
    public DataAccessHelper getDaoHelper() {
    if (daoHelper== null) {
        Injector.get().inject(daoHelper);
    }
    return daoHelper;
  }
}
```

Things i have tried

1. simply use a Mockapplication and add new new SpringComponentInjector(this, context,true), this causes a exception telling me to do an init on the application (Apllication.init())

   1. trial and error solutions

I know it doesnt seem much what i have tried, but im really out of options right now :S

Comment: Can you please display the null pointer exception from the error log output?

Answer (score 2):

You need to register an Application which has a link to a ServetContext and a WicketFilter. This can be done programmatically:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(LOCATIONS);
    XS2RAWebApp webApp = new XS2RAWebApp() {
        @Override
        public void init() {
            getComponentInstantiationListeners().add(new SpringComponentInjector(this, context,true));
        }
    };
    ThreadContext.setApplication(webApp);
    webApp.setServletContext(new MockServletContext());
webApp.setWicketFilter(new WicketFilter(webApp));
webApp.initApplication();

    ResponseUpdateTask updatetask = new ResponseUpdateTask();
    updatetask.run();
}
```